iOS Facebook permissions not showing to the user
I'm trying to get some facebook user's permissions but not all of them are listed to the user to grant/decline.
Using the FBLoginButton and setting the permissions to:
- email
- pages_show_list
- instagram_basic
- pages_read_engagement
- business_management
- instagram_manage_insights

The user is presented only with public_profile (mandatory) and email, the rest are not shown to be granted/declined.
Any subsequent request doesn't show them either.
I also set button.authType = .rerequest
To note that when I created a new facebook account for testing and this worked just fine. Could it be a particular setting on some accounts to not ask these permissions.
The account(s) with issues are personal accounts (mine / colleagues)
What am I missing here?

If those users had already granted some of the permissions before, then they won't be asked for them again. Have them check under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

I already tried removing any previous connections from the applications tab, it behaves exactly the same.

Do you have those permissions approved by Facebook yet? Do the user accounts have a role in the app?

The permissions are approved by Facebook. The user accounts have no role in the app, just typical accounts.
